# Not able to create mapping in elastic search

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I'm trying to run elasticsearch for the first time. http://localhost:9200 returns correct response. Now I'm trying to create my own mapping with the following file through postman:

**[POST] localhost:9200/persons**

```
{
  "mappings" : {
    "person":{
      "properties": {
        "personid":{
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "name":{
          "type": "string"
        },
        "email":{
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But whenever i post it I get the following

```
{
    "error": "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/persons/] and method [POST], allowed: [GET, DELETE, PUT, HEAD]",
    "status": 405
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping

```
put  localhost:9200/persons  --->  change post to put
{

  "mappings" : {                ----> remove person
      "properties": {
        "personid":{
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "name":{
          "type": "text"       ---> change string to text 
        },
        "email":{
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

If you intend to make personid and other field as subfields of person and access using person.personid then use below

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "person": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "personid": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "email": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it worked!!! but seems like their documentation is not updated

Comment: make sure to check document of elastic search version which you are using.

Answer (score 2):

> To add mapping in elastic search always use PUT method

```
PUT  localhost:9200/index_name/_mapping

{
  "mappings" : {
    "person":{
      "properties": {
        "personid":{
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "name":{
          "type": "string"
        },
        "email":{
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```